# Replacing for loop with apply fuctions

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, sapply, stringdist

I want to replace nested for loops with appropriate apply function in R.

I declare a matrix with the following dimensions - ncol is 412 and nrow 2164

```
dist.name.enh <- matrix(NA, ncol = length(WW_name),nrow = length(Px_name))
```

The for loops for calculating the string distances are as below

```
for(i in 1:length(WW_name)) {
  for(j in 1:length(Px_name)) {

    dist.name.enh[j,i]<-stringdist(tolower(WW_name)[i],
                                   tolower(Px_name)[j],
                                   method = "lv")
  }  
}
```

How do I avoid the for loops as it is taking very long to return the matrix.

The code is looked up from [R-bloggers website](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fuzzy-string-matching-a-survival-skill-to-tackle-unstructured-information/)

Comment: Remove the print command.

Comment: @user2974951 removing the print command does not help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `outer` here which will apply the function to every combination of `x` and `y`.

```
outer(tolower(WW_name), tolower(Px_name), stringdist::stringdist, method = "lv")
```

For example,

```
x <- c("random", "strings", "to", "test")
y <- c("another", "string", "test")

outer(x, y, stringdist::stringdist, method = "lv")

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    6    6    6
#[2,]    7    1    6
#[3,]    6    5    3
#[4,]    6    5    0
```